# How can I define a custom class of keywords in listings?

Tags: listings, highlighting

How can I define a custom class of keywords in `listings`?

In the C# listing below, keywords, such as `using`, `namespace`, etc., get highlighted as desired. However, I would like to define a custom class of keywords  called "attributes", that would allow me to declare `Test`, `Assert`, etc. as attributes and highlight them in a custom style (e.g. cyan color). How can I do that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage[driver=pdftex, margin=2.54cm]{geometry}


\definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.64,0.08,0.08}
\definecolor{xmlcomments}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{types}{rgb}{0.17,0.57,0.68}

\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
showspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
breaklines=true,
showstringspaces=false,
breakatwhitespace=true,
escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords}\bfseries,
stringstyle=\color{redstrings},
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
morekeywords={  abstract, event, new, struct,
                as, explicit, null, switch,
                base, extern, object, this,
                bool, false, operator, throw,
                break, finally, out, true,
                byte, fixed, override, try,
                case, float, params, typeof,
                catch, for, private, uint,
                char, foreach, protected, ulong,
                checked, goto, public, unchecked,
                class, if, readonly, unsafe,
                const, implicit, ref, ushort,
                continue, in, return, using,
                decimal, int, sbyte, virtual,
                default, interface, sealed, volatile,
                delegate, internal, short, void,
                do, is, sizeof, while,
                double, lock, stackalloc,
                else, long, static,
                enum, namespace, string, GeneticAlgorithmHarmonizer, var},
                %list your attributes here
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true]
using System;
using Harmonizer;
using NUnit.Framework;
using ScoreManagement;

namespace TestingLibrary
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ScoreManagementUnitTests
    {
        private const KeySignature KeySignature = ScoreManagement.KeySignature.CMajor;
        private const TimeSignature TimeSignature =     ScoreManagement.TimeSignature.FourFour;

        [Test]
        public void AddConstructorParameters_AddingKeySignature_ReturnsTrue()
        {
            var score = new Score(KeySignature);

             Assert.IsTrue(score.KeySignature == KeySignature);
        }
    }
}

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want this in the main document text (not in listings) then it will be much more robust to not do it in tex and simply use your editor to add `\keyword{}` around `a`, `b`, and `c` and then define `\keyword` to be a suitable `\textcolor{}{..}`

Comment: Or use `\lstinline` or `\lstMakeShortInline` from the `listings` package. In any case, if you want to highlight something in the main text, you will need to delimit it, somehow.

Comment: Sorry for the obscurity - i would like the highlighting to occur in the `listings`. I updated the question

Comment: Please edit your question and add some sample C# code to illustrate and list (as precisely as possible) what should be highlighted in what style, what should not get highlighted at all, etc.

Comment: How about adding this line to your lstset? `emph={Test,Assert},emphstyle={\color{cyan}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `listings` package has an internal macro called `\lst@InstallKeywords` for exactly that purpose: defining a custom class of keywords. In your case, invoking

```
\lst@InstallKeywords k{attributes}{attributestyle}\slshape{attributestyle}{}ld
```

creates four keys: `attributes`, `moreattributes`, `deleteattributes`, and `attributestyle` (which is set to `\slshape` by default). All four keys have *almost* the same usage as their `keywords` equivalents; the only difference is that they do not accept any optional argument, which means that they only allow for one class of "attribute" keywords.

However, if needed, you can define a whole *family* of "attribute" keywords (within which you can have several "attribute" keyword classes) with another internal macro called `\lst@InstallFamily`; the latter has exactly the same syntax as `\lst@InstallKeywords`. See the manual for more details.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage[driver=pdftex, margin=2.54cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\lst@InstallKeywords k{attributes}{attributestyle}\slshape{attributestyle}{}ld
\makeatother


\definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.64,0.08,0.08}
\definecolor{xmlcomments}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{types}{rgb}{0.17,0.57,0.68}

\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
showspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
breaklines=true,
showstringspaces=false,
breakatwhitespace=true,
escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords}\bfseries,
stringstyle=\color{redstrings},
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
morekeywords={  abstract, event, new, struct,
                as, explicit, null, switch,
                base, extern, object, this,
                bool, false, operator, throw,
                break, finally, out, true,
                byte, fixed, override, try,
                case, float, params, typeof,
                catch, for, private, uint,
                char, foreach, protected, ulong,
                checked, goto, public, unchecked,
                class, if, readonly, unsafe,
                const, implicit, ref, ushort,
                continue, in, return, using,
                decimal, int, sbyte, virtual,
                default, interface, sealed, volatile,
                delegate, internal, short, void,
                do, is, sizeof, while,
                double, lock, stackalloc,
                else, long, static,
                enum, namespace, string, GeneticAlgorithmHarmonizer, var},
moreattributes={Assert, Test}, % etc...
attributestyle = \bfseries\color{RubineRed}, % (for instance)
%deleteattributes={Assert}, % just a test
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true]
using System;
using Harmonizer;
using NUnit.Framework;
using ScoreManagement;

namespace TestingLibrary
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ScoreManagementUnitTests
    {
        private const KeySignature KeySignature = ScoreManagement.KeySignature.CMajor;
        private const TimeSignature TimeSignature =     ScoreManagement.TimeSignature.FourFour;

        [Test]
        public void AddConstructorParameters_AddingKeySignature_ReturnsTrue()
        {
            var score = new Score(KeySignature);

             Assert.IsTrue(score.KeySignature == KeySignature);
        }
    }
}

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: dude - you're a rockstar

Comment: @AidenStrydom `\m/(**)\m/`